# LINQ vb.net groupby on multiple columns with aggregate information

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following linq query:

```
(From document In DocumentEntities
 Group Join transactionRow In TransactionEntities.Where(Function(tran) tran.PaymentType = "Charge" And tran.Amount <> 0 And (Not tran.Void.HasValue OrElse (tran.Void.HasValue AndAlso Not tran.Void.Value)))
     On document.DocumentId Equals transactionRow.DocumentId
     Into foundTransactions = Group
     From foundTransaction In foundTransactions.DefaultIfEmpty()
  Group Join documentInstrument In DocumentInstrumentEntities.Where(Function(docInst) docInst.IsPrimary)
      On document.DocumentId Equals documentInstrument.DocumentId
      Into relatedDocumentInstruments = Group
  From documentInstrument In relatedDocumentInstruments.DefaultIfEmpty()
  Join instrument In InstrumentEntities
      On documentInstrument.InstrumentId Equals instrument.InstrumentId
Where (document.DocumentId = 241083 OR document.DocumentId = 241084 OR     document.DocumentId = 241085 OR document.DocumentId = 241086 OR     document.DocumentId = 241087 OR document.DocumentId = 241090 OR     document.DocumentId = 241091 OR document.DocumentId = 241092 OR document.DocumentId = 241093 OR document.DocumentId = 241094 OR document.DocumentId = 241095 OR document.DocumentId = 241096 OR document.DocumentId = 241097 OR document.DocumentId = 241098 OR document.DocumentId = 241099 OR document.DocumentId = 241100 OR document.DocumentId = 241101 OR document.DocumentId = 241088 OR document.DocumentId = 241089)
Order By instrument.Name
Select New With
{
 .Amount = foundTransaction.Amount,
 .Code = instrument.Code,
 .Instrument = instrument.Name,
 .InstrumentId = instrument.InstrumentId,
 .Pages = document.Pages
}).GroupBy(Function(instrument) new with {instrument.Code,     instrument.Instrument})
.Select(Function(grouping) new with {.Code = grouping.Key.Code, .Instrument = grouping.Key.Instrument})
```

Which gives me a nice, grouped list of instruments and codes sorted by instrument.name. Now I need to know how to access the items in the actual grouping to do aggregate functions. For example, I would like to have the SUM(amount) returned in my final result but I am not sure how to access the actual IGrouping for each key so that I can get the aggregates I need.

So, for instance I want my new FINAL select to look something like this:

```
.Select(Function(grouping) new with {.Code = grouping.Key.Code, .Instrument = grouping.Key.Instrument, .Amount = SUM(grouping.amount)})
```

I know there would be a lambda in there on the aggregate function but I it is just pseudocode so I can try to explain what I am after.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted suggestion is the correct syntax, and I had tried that but had gotten an exception, so I needed to call .ToList() after the groupby.

Here is the query that works:

```
(From document In DocumentEntities
 Group Join transactionRow In TransactionEntities.Where(Function(tran) tran.PaymentType = "Charge" And tran.Amount <> 0 And (Not tran.Void.HasValue OrElse (tran.Void.HasValue AndAlso Not tran.Void.Value)))
     On document.DocumentId Equals transactionRow.DocumentId
     Into foundTransactions = Group
     From foundTransaction In foundTransactions.DefaultIfEmpty()
  Group Join documentInstrument In DocumentInstrumentEntities.Where(Function(docInst) docInst.IsPrimary)
      On document.DocumentId Equals documentInstrument.DocumentId
      Into relatedDocumentInstruments = Group
  From documentInstrument In relatedDocumentInstruments.DefaultIfEmpty()
  Join instrument In InstrumentEntities
      On documentInstrument.InstrumentId Equals instrument.InstrumentId
Where (document.DocumentId = 241083 OR document.DocumentId = 241084 OR    document.DocumentId = 241085 OR document.DocumentId = 241086 OR document.DocumentId = 241087 OR document.DocumentId = 241090 OR document.DocumentId = 241091 OR document.DocumentId = 241092 OR document.DocumentId = 241093 OR document.DocumentId = 241094 OR document.DocumentId = 241095 OR document.DocumentId = 241096 OR document.DocumentId = 241097 OR document.DocumentId = 241098 OR document.DocumentId = 241099 OR document.DocumentId = 241100 OR document.DocumentId = 241101 OR document.DocumentId = 241088 OR document.DocumentId = 241089)
Order By instrument.Name
Select New With
{
 .Amount = foundTransaction.Amount,
 .Code = instrument.Code,
 .Instrument = instrument.Name,
 .InstrumentId = instrument.InstrumentId,
 .Pages = document.Pages
}).GroupBy(Function(instrument) new with {instrument.Code,    instrument.Instrument}).ToList().Select(Function(grouping) new with {.Code = grouping.Key.Code, .Instrument = grouping.Key.Instrument, .TotalFees= grouping.Sum(Function(item) item.Amount)}).OrderBy(Function(item) item.Instrument).ThenBy(Function(item) item.Code).ToList()
```

Comment: Using a `ToList`, you lose the benefit of EntityFramework on the part that performs the aggregation. From there, it's not LINQ to Entities but LINQ to Object which processe the data. It's a real shame! Tell us more about this exception.

Comment: Here is the exception: Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IGrouping to type system.collections.IEnumerable.

Comment: In my particular instance, I need to take the query and .ToList() it into a variable and THEN perform the grouping (short story, I don't need to go into why here) but the grouping no longer works on my local variable containing the results. Why would that be?

Comment: So basically, I need this to work against a List(Of T), not Linq to Entities. The query works perfectly in Linq to Entities but not against just a list of results (from the original query).

Comment: Dim groupedResults = tempResults.GroupBy(Function(instrument) New With {instrument.Code, instrument.Instrument}).ToList() -- THIS DOES NOT DO ANY GROUPING. tempResult is just a List(Of object) (list of anonymous types projected from my original query). I really don't see why the grouping doesn't work here.

Comment: Yes because LINQ to Object use the default equality comparer. Implement your how comparer or use the [Tuple class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No, I just needed to specify the keys since vb.net uses mutable properties on anonymous types. So this works: Dim groupedResults = tempResults.GroupBy(Function(instrument) New With { KEY instrument.Code, KEY instrument.Instrument}).ToList() -- This works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A group is a sequence.
So, just try:

```
.Amount = grouping.Sum(Function(item) item.Amount)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too and I tried that but I get the following error: Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IGrouping to type system.collections.IEnumerable. Using LinqPad

Comment: I suspect there's more detail to your error message, since `IGrouping<T,U>` extends `IEnumerable<U>`